# AWS : Elastic Beanstalk With Static IP Address for external Registrar

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for a way to be able to provide my client a load balanced solution on AWS, preferably using elastic beanstalk, with a static IP address for them to use at their registrar for the CNAME.

The majority of my clients are able to point their NS to route53 which allows me to manage their DNS and use alias records to handle the change in IP address with the elastic load balancer in Elastic Beanstalk.

I have a client who isn't in a position to allow me to manage their DNS records though route53. They have too much in play on the TLD to offload this, but is willing to point a CNAME records to an IP address.

There's plenty of documentation I've found for setting up a vpc and a nat gateway for reaching external resources that require an static IP but I'm hard pressed to find a clear cut, easy to implement solution, for hosting content with needs of an inbound static IP.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.

Let's say the customer's domain name is `example.net` and they want `magicapp.example.net` to be served by your platform.

You can create a Route 53 hosted zone for `magicapp.example.net`.  There is nothing that says you need control of their entire domain, and nothing to prevent you from creating a hosted zone for only a subdomain.

Have the customer create 4 NS records with their current DNS provider *for the subdomain* `magicapp.example.net` *only*, referencing the 4 name servers that Route 53 assigned to your hosted zone.  This is called creating a delegation for a subdomain -- delegating it to you.

Now, you can provision the Route 53 records normally, but only for that subdomain, which is the only thing they have delegated to you.

With this setup, you can also get DNS-validated certificates from ACM.

Option 2.

Register your own domain, e.g. `example.com`.  (Or, use a domain that you already own.)

Configure it with a hosted zone in Route 53.

Create an A record Alias as e.g. `customer-name.example.com` pointing to your beanstalk app.

Have the customer create a CNAME record pointing to `customer-name.example.com`.

Now, if you ever need to change where that domain is pointing, you can edit the record in the hosted zone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not possible to point static IPs to a load balancer without some tricks,

But you could use this [Using static IP addresses for Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/)

note 1: you can only use Application load balancer on elastic beanstalk in the enviroment creation moment. if you create the enviroment with single instance and change, it will create a classic load balancer automatically.

note 2: your application load balancer must be internal.